# How do I set the name of the log file in `screen`?

Tags: linux, logging, debian, gnu-screen

Is it possible to set the name of the `screen` log file? Normally it's called `screenlog.n`, but I need to know the exact name of a log for a script that I'm writing. I hope somebody can help me. I didn't find anything in the man page for `screen`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are in `screen`, enter command mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and use the `:logfile` command:

> Command: **logfile** *filename*
>   Command: **logfile** *flush secs*
>
> Defines the name the log files will get. The default is `screenlog.%n`. The second form changes the number of seconds screen will wait before flushing the logfile buffer to the file-system. The default value is 10 seconds.

Logging is turned off by default, so to turn it on, use the command `:log on` to enable logging.

> Command: **log** [*state*]
>
> Begins/ends logging of the current window to the file `screenlog.n` in the window's default directory, where n is the number of the current window. This filename can be changed with the `logfile` command. If no parameter is given, the logging state is toggled. The session log is appended to the previous contents of the file if it already exists. The current contents and the contents of the scrollback history are not included in the session log. Default is `off`.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Log.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a `logfile` command for it, described in the man page (as of version 4.01).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast Answer! I saw the logfile option in the man, but i really dont know how to set this, because its not a parameter. It have to be set in the .screenrc, am i right?